# BASH test exist directory with a variable as path

Tags: bash, testing

I would do a simple test to know if a directory exist in a bash script.

The directory path is in a variable.
My test works with the path of file but does not work with the variable.

```
 # if [ -d $test ]; then echo ok; fi 
 # >> ### NO OUTPUT ###
 # if [ -d ~/dir/ ]; then echo ok; fi 
 # >> ok
 # echo $test
 # >> ~/dir/
```

I define the variable mysef by :

```
 # test="~/dir/"
```

I don't understand why it does not work with my variable whereas it contains the same path.

Thanks

Comment: No need to add `Solved` in the title, @Quentin. It is clear when you mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test doesn't work with the variable because it contains the *tilde* (`~`).

You can use `eval` but the recommended approach would be to use `${HOME}` instead of `~` in the variable.  Try:

```
test="${HOME}/dir"
[[ -d $test ]] && echo ok
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `# test="~/dir/"` to `test=~/dir/` and you should be good to go.